# How to iterably enter multiple list of strings into multiple search boxes with selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I need to enter 3 different values into 3 different search box fields then submit the form.

I will need to iterate the same process several times. I currently understand how to do this with one value and one search box field:

```
import csv
with open(r'C:\Users\username\Documents\Province\folder\list_titles.txt', 
newline='') as inputfile:
list_1 = list(csv.reader(inputfile)) 

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://vch.cochrane.ca/VCH/city/propsearch
/pigeneralinquiry.aspx")

for query in list_1:
    driver.find_element_by_id
("ctl00_MainContentView_rollSearchControl_LINCNumber").send_keys(query)
    driver.find_element_by_id
("ctl00_MainContentView_rollSearchControl_LINCNumber").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

In the above code, I am using a list to conduct the task in iterations. How can I do the same thing but infill 3 search box fields before submitting the form?

Comment: `list_1` is the list with 3 strings (values), right? And all 3 input fields have the same `@id` `"ctl00_MainContentView_rollSearchControl_LINCNumber"`?

Comment: list one only has a list of one string value to infill a single search field in iterations. All 3 input fields have different ids. my code example is showing how to do the task by entering one value in one search box and submitting the form. What I do not understand how to do is enter 3 different values into 3 different search boxes then submit the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution loops through the list but explicitly lists the search fields in the the program.

```
list_1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("URL with search fields")
for query in list_1:
    driver.find_element_by_name("searchfield_1").send_keys(query[0])
    driver.find_element_by_name("searchfield_2").send_keys(query[1])
    driver.find_element_by_name("searchfield_3").send_keys(query[2])

driver.find_element_by_name("submitbutton").click()
sleep(2)
driver.back()
driver.refresh()
sleep(2)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: This will just enter `147` to first input field, `258` to second and `369` to third and then submit the form...

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for :) Thanks for your help